# MySQL - Selecionar os valores das tuplas utilizando nomes de colunas dinâmicos

Tags: mysql, sql

É um filtro onde o usuário seleciona os dias da semana e envia pro banco filtrar porém não estou conseguindo realizar a filtragem.
A tabela tem como coluna os dias da semana com vários registros. Por exemplo tem empresa que funciona de seg a sex então se cadastra na linha com id 1 na coluna seg o horário 8:00-18:00 ter 8:00-18:00 qua 8:00-18:00 qui 8:00-18:00 sex 8:00-18:00 sab Fechado dom Fechado e a empresa recebe o id dessa linha como FK. São varias linhas com horarios de dom a sab diferentes. 
Agora o filtro, se ele passar segunda então quero selecionar todas as linhas onde a coluna segunda é diferente de fechado. 
Fiz assim:

```
select * from funcionamento where 
    (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where 
        table_name = 'funcionamento' AND column_name like '%segunda') 
    != 'Fechado';
```

Porém não funcionou, ele acha a coluna segunda porém não os campos com valor diferente de fechado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tente postar imagem de como está modelado seu banco, não consegui compreender muito bem, mas parece que ta faltando usar inner join

Comment: Pensei em usar inner join mas não consegui pensar em uma forma

Comment: Na minha ideia ao trocar a subquery pelo nome da coluna ele iria filtrar todos os valores diferente de fechado mas não é o que acontece

Comment: Mas se column_name like '%segunda' como poderia ser  != 'Fechado'?

Comment: Executando a subquery e pegando o nome da coluna, quando substituisse a subquery ficaria select * from funcionamento where funcionamento_string_segunda != 'Fechado'; e então ele filtraria. Pelo menos deveria ser.

Comment: Pesquise por prepared statement. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: pela imagem da sua tabela não é só pegar **select * from funcionamento where funcionamento_string_segunda != 'Fechado'** ?

Comment: Não é, porque como é um filtro e o usuário escolhe os dias da semana eu não saberei se será segunda, terça, quarta...Não sabemos qual a coluna verificar se é diferente de fechado, só quando ele escolher

Comment: Já tentei concatenar o valor do checkbox com o nome da coluna mas também não resolve. Por exemplo value='segunda'    e na query= '...CONCAT('funcionamento_string_',:dia)... mas a query não aceita

Comment: Resolvi com o uso de uma view. Obrigado a todos

Comment: Eu normalizaria este modelo.

Comment: E como você normalizaria?Pra mim já está na 1,2 e 3 FN